# C# Serial Port Communication Time

Tags: c#, serial-port

Recently I have started working on small in house project, and need some help.

I am writing application to read and send (1 & 0 ) signal on USB serial port  with help of C# application. I am using toggle switch to reset system. My requirement is, if I continuously press toggle switch for 3 or 5 sec, the system should wait for it and after that it should system start responding.

rec = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();

if ((rec.Substring(13, 1) == "1"))  // 1 indicate high signal
{ 
   Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch(); // Begin timing 
      stopwatch.Start(); 
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000); // Stop timing 
      stopwatch.Stop(); 
      TimeSpan t = stopwatch.Elapsed;
      
      if (t.Seconds.ToString() == "3") 
      {
          CallFunc();
      } else {
          //Continue Operation.....   
      }

Looking forward to your response.

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @BugFinder: OP's request is probably how to send 1's or 0's using a USB port....

Comment: or maybe not.. who knows?

Comment: I can send & receive signal. My question is, if I am able to read 1's at that time I want to keep it continuously reading for 3 secs. And if time is less then 3 secs no action is required.

Comment: if ((rec.Substring(13, 1) == "1"))
{
   Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
   // Begin timing
   stopwatch.Start();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
   // Stop timing
   stopwatch.Stop();
   TimeSpan t = stopwatch.Elapsed;

Comment: if (t.Seconds.ToString() == "3" )
{
  CallCloseFunc();
 }
But this code doesn't give consistent result.

Comment: rec = mySerialPort.ReadExisting();

if ((rec.Substring(13, 1) == "1"))
{
   Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
   // Begin timing
   stopwatch.Start();
   System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(3000);
   // Stop timing
   stopwatch.Stop();
   TimeSpan t = stopwatch.Elapsed;

Comment: Your setup is poorly described.  How does this *"toggle switch"* send data to a *"USB serial port"*?  Normally those are not compatible devices that would be connected together.  And if you're going to show us code, put it in your "question" by editing it, instead of making unreadable comments.

Comment: Dear Sawdust, I have edited my question and tried to format it. Please review it and let me know your comments. Thanks in advance.